# Socket.io: io.on('connection) repeats three times

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

The following is an excerpt from some server side code located in the entry point of the application:

```
const app = express()
const chatServer = require('http').Server(app);
chatServer.listen(3000)
const io = require('socket.io')(chatServer);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('ABC')
  socket.on('send-chat-message', message => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message', message)
  })
});
```

Upon running my dev server I expected to see 'ABC' print once to the console. However, it is printing three times (ABC, ABC, ABC) instead. Why does this happen? The io variable is NOT used anywhere else in the application. I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with client side logic  (since no requests are made by the client at this point) And for complete reference, the entire app.js code is displayed below:

```
const express = require('express')
require('./db/mongoose')
const playerRouter = require('./routers/player')
const contractRouter = require('./routers/contract')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const hbs = require('express-handlebars')
const path = require('path')
const passport = require('passport');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');

// Define paths for Express config
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/views')
const partialsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/partials')
const layoutPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/layouts')

const app = express()
const chatServer = require('http').Server(app);
chatServer.listen(3000)
const io = require('socket.io')(chatServer);

// Passport Config
require('./middleware/passport')(passport);

//Setup handlebars engine and views location
app.engine('hbs', hbs({
  extname: 'hbs',
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  layoutsDir: layoutPath,
  partialsDir: partialsPath,
}));

app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.set('views', viewsPath)

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('ABC')
  socket.on('send-chat-message', message => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message', message)
  })
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json())

// Express session
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Connect flash
app.use(flash());

// Global variables
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user
  next();
});

app.use(playerRouter)
app.use(contractRouter)

module.exports = app
```

Here is the client side code (for brevity I did not include the entire HTML file):

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000')
const messageContainer = document.getElementById('message-container')
const messageForm = document.getElementById('send-container')
const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input')

socket.on('chat-message', message => {
  appendMessage(`Opponent: ${message}`)
})


messageForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const message = messageInput.value
  appendMessage(`You: ${message}`)
  socket.emit('send-chat-message', message)
  messageInput.value = ''
})

const appendMessage = (message) => {
  const messageElement = document.createElement('div')
  messageElement.innerText = message
  messageContainer.append(messageElement)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, the message 'ABC' is rendered every time a connection to the client is established.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

// Here declare fiel static, as index.html, css, javascript.
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../public")));

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("ABC");
  socket.on("send-chat-message", message => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("chat-message", message);
  });
});

http.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("Starting...");
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="message-container"></div>
    <form id="send-container">
      <input id="message-input" type="text" />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      const socket = io();
      const messageContainer = document.getElementById("message-container");
      const messageForm = document.getElementById("send-container");
      const messageInput = document.getElementById("message-input");

      socket.on("chat-message", message => {
        appendMessage(`Opponent: ${message}`);
      });

      messageForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const message = messageInput.value;
        console.log(message);
        appendMessage(`You: ${message}`);
        socket.emit("send-chat-message", message);
        messageInput.value = "";
      });

      const appendMessage = message => {
        const messageElement = document.createElement("div");
        messageElement.innerText = message;
        messageContainer.append(messageElement);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here you can see the code working live.

I hope it helps. Any questions comment.

https://codesandbox.io/s/expressjs-chat-9v8lo

Comment: Your conclusion is not correct.  The ABC message has only to do with socket.io connections being initiated and nothing to do with the `send-chat-message`.  This issue is likely caused by something connection-related.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I will modify my answer, thanks

Comment: So, what was the problem?  What was the fix?

Comment: I think the problem is on the client side. Somehow, three clients are connecting simultaneously to the server.

Check your code, and it works correctly you can see it in the link.